# Стилизация андроид Приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

В приложения программно (Java коде) вывожу несколько LinearLayout. Не как не могу поставить программно этому LinearLayout фон имеющего drawable. И еще помогите пожалуйста Нарисовать в Drawable маленькую полоску снизу (типа границы).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture);
```

Для линий, можете в разметке вставлять:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/silver />
```

**UPD**

Если же создаете динамично то сначала в главном линере разметки задайте ориентацию, например вертикальную, а потом добавляйте другие:

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

    // Добавляем линер, с нужным бэкграундом
    LinearLayout layout = new  LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(llp);
    layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.index);

    // Добавляем полоску снизу
    View v = new View(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    v.setLayoutParams(lll);

    linearLayout.addView(layout);
    linearLayout.addView(v);
```

Comment: это конечно круто но в приложения есть надобность делать почти всю разметку программно так что второй с @color/silver не подходит. И я делал linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture); но он меня выкидывал почему то((

Comment: LinearLayout pub = new LinearLayout(c);
            pub.setLayoutParams(params03);
            pub.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            pub.setPadding(3,3,3,10);
            pub.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.publines); разметка выглядит примерно так

Comment: @Джидай дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за помощь